# vue js failed to "reactive"

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

i am following this tutorial https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering. the page works fine without error on console but i cant change the message via console to showing "app2.message" and give me error "#app2 is not defined". its not working like they said

> We have already created our very first Vue app! This looks pretty similar to rendering a string template, but Vue has done a lot of work under the hood. The data and the DOM are now linked, and everything is now reactive. How do we know? Open your browser’s JavaScript console (right now, on this page) and set app.message to a different value. You should see the rendered example above update accordingly.

[image]

here is my script:

```
window.addEventListener('load',
function() {

    var app2 = new Vue({
        el: '#app-2',
        data: {
            message: 'You loaded this page on ' + new Date().toLocaleString()
        }
    })

}, false);
```

this is how i include the js

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<title>3R Inventory | @yield('title')</title>

<!-- Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::to('css/app.css') }}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::to('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::to('/js/tigaer.js') }}"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: app2 is not a global variable, because you're declaring it within a function.

Comment: i remove the function inclluding `window.addEventListener...bla bla` but still doesnt work. it still says `#app2 is not defined`

Comment: According to Vue instances in your page, you can access them as global variables (e.g: $vm0).

Comment: You need to have global variable like window.app2 = new Vue. Then you can access it. You cant access while declaring local variable. You should use $vm0. I strongly recommend using Vue Dev tools for chrome!

Comment: ah it works @ElDanielo but i need to move `<script type=javascript...` to the bottom before </body>. by the way do we really need `window.onload` or something like that?

Comment: No, you do not need that part. No need for window.onload for Vue.

Comment: To clarify whether or not you need to instantiate Vue in load or onload; it depends on where you put the script that instantiates the Vue. If the script is in the header, as it is in the question, yes, absolutely you need to instantiate the Vue in the load event because at the time the script is run, `#app-2` is not yet on the page. If you include the script at the bottom of the page, then you do not need load event because the DOM elements will already be loaded.